# Is the word "decadally" correct?

Tags: word-request

Like *daily = every day* and *monthly = every month*, does *decadally = every ten days* exist?

Comment: [Related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/363469/116151) on EL&U.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm searching for the adverb, not the noun, however I see  that an [answer of that question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/363489/183634) says tri-monthly or thrice-monthly, I'll use one of those, thank you!

Comment: There are hundreds of written instances of [*decadally*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22decadally%22) in Google Books, but to be honest I'd rather just push the envelope a bit and use the common-as-muck adjectival form [*ten yearly*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ten+yearly%22) adverbially.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is asking for every ten **days** not years. Years would be "[decennially](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decennially#English)", though that too is obscure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We produce some files on 10th, 20th and at the end of every month and we call them "decadali" in Italian, but I need the correspondent of the adverb "decadalmente".

Comment: @Kys I think the misunderstanding comes from the fact that _decadale/i_ in Italian means _every ten days_ whereas _decennale/i_ means every ten years, I confirm I need the adverb for every ten **days**.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single word or phrase that means "every ten days", unless you want to get picturesque and primitive and say something like "every **two hands** of days".  Also remember that you want to use a common phrase that everyone will immediately recognize, so "every 10 days" is your best bet.

But that doesn't apply to all time periods.  For fun [here is a list of the names of various lengths of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_time#List), although it doesn't include compound terms like "bi-weekly" or "every other year", and a few others like "sesquicentennial" (150-year anniversary of something).

Comment: Isn't _thrice-monthly_ acceptable? My sentence is _... three different periodicities: daily, thrice-monthly and monthly._

Comment: "Thrice-monthly" isn't "every 10 days", though.   What about February?

Comment: We produce some files on 10th, 20th and at the end of every month and we call them "decadali" in Italian, see my comment to my question above.

Comment: The issue I take with "thrice monthly" is that it does not suggest that the event will happen at regular intervals, only that it will happen three times over the course of a month. If something happens twice in the first week and also near the end of each month, it happens thrice monthly, but not every ten days.